# Delete multiple files(objects) listed in a ".txt" file with "gsutil" (GCS)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil, google-cloud-shell, google-cloud-storage

I could delete the 3 files(objects), **"apple.jpg"**, **"orange.png"** and **"kiwi.gif"** on **GCS** with the **"gsutil"** command below on **Cloud Shell**:

```
(Hint: gs://<Bucket_Name>/<File_Name>)

gsutil rm gs://test.com/apple.jpg gs://test.com/orange.png gs://test.com/kiwi.gif
```

Now, I want to delete **the 3 same files**, **"apple.jpg"**, **"orange.png"** and **"kiwi.gif"** with **"fruits.txt"** file which lists **the 3 same files**:

**fruits.txt:**

```
gs://test.com/apple.jpg
gs://test.com/orange.png
gs://test.com/kiwi.gif
```

However, I don't know what command with **"gsutil"** to run to delete them with **"fruits.txt"** file.
What command should I run?

Answer (score 4):

This command with **"gsutil"** works to delete **the 3 same files** with **"fruits.txt"** file:

```
cat fruits.txt | gsutil -m rm -I
```

Actually, there is a hint on
[Google Cloud Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rm) for **GCS(Google Cloud Storage)** with **"gsutil"**:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using Linux based shell commands.  I tested the following and it worked:

```
gsutil rm $(cat fruits.txt)
```

The `$(cat fruits.txt)` using Linux shell to take the content of the file `fruits.txt` and supply that as parameters to the `gsutil` command.

See also:

- [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)